# Why does Celery work in Python shell, but not in my Django views? (import problem)

Tags: python, django, unix, import, celery

I installed Celery (latest stable version.)
I have a directory called `/home/myuser/fable/jobs`.  Inside this directory, I have a file called tasks.py:

```
from celery.decorators import task
from celery.task import Task

class Submitter(Task):
    def run(self, post, **kwargs):
        return "Yes, it works!!!!!!"
```

Inside this directory, I also have a file called celeryconfig.py:

```
BROKER_HOST = "localhost"
BROKER_PORT = 5672
BROKER_USER = "abc"
BROKER_PASSWORD = "xyz"
BROKER_VHOST = "fablemq"

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("tasks", )
```

In my `/etc/profile`, I have these set as my PYTHONPATH:

- `PYTHONPATH=/home/myuser/fable:/home/myuser/fable/jobs`

So I run my Celery worker using the console (`$ celeryd --loglevel=INFO`), and I try it out.
I open the Python console and import the tasks.  Then, I run the Submitter.

```
>>> import fable.jobs.tasks as tasks
>>> s = tasks.Submitter()
>>> s.delay("abc")
<AsyncResult: d70d9732-fb07-4cca-82be-d7912124a987>
```

Everything works, as you can see in my console

```
[2011-01-09 17:30:05,766: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.Submitter[d70d9732-fb07-4cca-82be-d7912124a987] succeeded in 0.0398268699646s:
```

But when I go into my Django's views.py and run the exact 3 lines of code as above, I get this:

```
[2011-01-09 17:25:20,298: ERROR/MainProcess] Unknown task ignored: "Task of kind 'fable.jobs.tasks.Submitter' is not registered, please make sure it's imported.": {'retries': 0, 'task': 'fable.jobs.tasks.Submitter', 'args': ('abc',), 'expires': None, 'eta': None, 'kwargs': {}, 'id': 'eb5c65b4-f352-45c6-96f1-05d3a5329d53'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myuser/mysite-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/worker/listener.py", line 321, in receive_message
    eventer=self.event_dispatcher)
  File "/home/myuser/mysite-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/worker/job.py", line 299, in from_message
    eta=eta, expires=expires)
  File "/home/myuser/mysite-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/worker/job.py", line 243, in __init__
    self.task = tasks[self.task_name]
  File "/home/myuser/mysite-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/registry.py", line 63, in __getitem__
    raise self.NotRegistered(str(exc))
NotRegistered: "Task of kind 'fable.jobs.tasks.Submitter' is not registered, please make sure it's imported."
```

It's weird, because the celeryd client does show that it's registered, when I launch it.

```
[2011-01-09 17:38:27,446: WARNING/MainProcess]  
Configuration ->
    . broker -> amqp://GOGOme@localhost:5672/fablemq
    . queues ->
        . celery -> exchange:celery (direct) binding:celery
    . concurrency -> 1
    . loader -> celery.loaders.default.Loader
    . logfile -> [stderr]@INFO
    . events -> OFF
    . beat -> OFF
    . tasks ->
        . tasks.Decayer
        . tasks.Submitter
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Are you also using django-celery or just celery by itself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe your tasks.py file needs to be in a django app (that's registered in settings.py) in order to be imported. Alternatively, you might try importing the tasks from an `__init__.py` file in your main project or one of the apps.

Also try starting celeryd from manage.py:

```
$ python manage.py celeryd -E -B -lDEBUG
```

(`-E` and `-B` may or may not be necessary, but that's what I use).

Comment: What do you mean "needs to be in a django app"?  I have tasks.py as a separate file, and import it in my views.py (import fable.jobs.tasks as tasks)

Comment: The tasks have to be registered in order to be seen by celery. That won't happen automatically in a `views.py` file, since that file isn't automatically loaded by python. I'm pretty sure that Celery will auto-find tasks in a file called `tasks.py` that's in a django app, or you can try importing the tasks in an `__init__.py`.

Comment: How come when I run the python shell (anywhere), it can detect and register the tasks?

Comment: I think I solved it. I put: sys.path.append("../jobs") to my views.py, and it worked!

Comment: Also, I had to run celeryd in the directory that contained celeryconfig.py

Answer (score 11):

This is what I did which finally worked

in Settings.py I added

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("myapp.jobs", )
```

under myapp folder I created a file called jobs.py

```
from celery.decorators import task

@task(name="jobs.add")
def add(x, y):
    return x * y
```

Then ran from commandline:  python manage.py celeryd -l info

in another shell i ran python manage.py shell, then

```
>>> from myapp.jobs import add
>>> result = add.delay(4, 4)
>>> result.result
```

and the i get:

16

The important point is that you have to rerun both command shells when you add a new function. You have to register the name both on the client and and on the server.

:-)

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it is so simple, but it was stopping the show on my project. They should include the  CELERY_IMPORTS line into the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. I was actually explicitly told that CELERY_IMPORTS isn't needed with django-celery, that djcelery.setup_loader() handled that, by a contributor in #celery. Disappointing that I had to chase a wild goose needlessly.

Comment: -1 The documentation say explicitly not to import it as "myapp.jobs". I know that in this example you are specifying the name but this example is much more confusing than doing it the right way. http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-naming-and-relative-imports

Comment: I had the same problem and by simple adding the CELERY_IMPORTS to my app it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

See Automatic Naming and Relative Imports, in the docs:

http://celeryq.org/docs/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-naming-and-relative-imports

The tasks name is "tasks.Submitter" (as listed in the celeryd output),
but you import the task as "fable.jobs.tasks.Submitter"

I guess the best solution here is if the worker also sees it as "fable.jobs.tasks.Submitter",
it makes more sense from an app perspective.

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("fable.jobs.tasks", )
```