# django-celery consumer can not receive tasks

Tags: django, sqlite, rabbitmq, celery

### Installation

I am using django(1.4) celery(3.0.13) with RabbitMQ(v3.0.4), the backend db is sqlite.

Celery was installed by `pip install django-celery`

### Setting

In setting.py:

```
# For django-celery
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://user:pwd@sd5:5672/8086'

### and adding 'djcelery' to INSTALLED_APPS
```

### Running

After setup the database with `south`, I start rabbitmq-server and `manage.py celery worker --loglevel=debug`

I could see the connection was established:

```
 -------------- celery@sd5 v3.0.16 (Chiastic Slide)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- [Configuration]
-- * - **** --- . broker:      amqp://utils@sd5:5672/8086
- ** ---------- . app:         default:0x8a5106c (djcelery.loaders.DjangoLoader)
- ** ---------- . concurrency: 2 (processes)
- ** ---------- . events:      OFF (enable -E to monitor this worker)
- ** ---------- 
    - *** --- * --- [Queues]
-- ******* ---- . celery:      exchange:celery(direct) binding:celery
--- ***** ----- 

[Tasks]
  . celery.backend_cleanup
      . celery.chain
  . celery.chord
  . celery.chord_unlock
  . celery.chunks
  . celery.group
  . celery.map
  . celery.starmap
  . utils.weixin.tasks.celery_add

[2013-03-19 19:50:00,460: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@sd5 ready.
[2013-03-19 19:50:00,483: INFO/MainProcess] consumer: Connected to amqp://utils@sd5:5672/8086.
[2013-03-19 19:50:00,498: DEBUG/MainProcess] consumer: Ready to accept tasks!
```

And in rabbit@sd5.log:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 19-Mar-2013::19:50:00 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.1655.0> (127.0.0.1:50087 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)
```

### Problem

Then I run my task `utils.weixin.tasks.celery_add` in `manage.py shell`:

```
>>> from utils.weixin.tasks import celery_add
>>> result = celery_add.delay(1,3)
>>> result.ready()
False
>>> result.get()
```

**hangup here forever...**

And, nothing show up in the log of celery worker and log of rabbitmq, not any 'received task' etc.

It seems that calling the task does not comunicate with worker.

---

### Question

What should I do to find out what has been done incorrectly. How should I fix this?

Appriciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854133/django-celery-tutorial-not-returning-results OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643065/why-does-celery-work-in-python-shell-but-not-in-my-django-views-import-proble/6899753#6899753